# ros indigo and opencv 3.0

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I just wanted to ask how to use ros indigo with opencv 3.0.

I installed ros-indigo-opencv3 and compiled the latest opencv from source.
When I create regular executables opencv 3.0 is used and it works fine,
but when I use catkin_make, some packages use opencv 2.4.x and some 3.0
and then they do not work together.
How do I hide opencv 2.4.x from being used?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199049/ros-indigo-and-opencv-3.0/) by [meleagrosy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20932/meleagrosy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-12-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-05-08**:
CAn you help me with ros indigo and opencv 2.4.8 please? What did you put in Cmake list file and xml file

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-30**:
Similar to http://answers.ros.org/question/214043/use-ros-indigo-opencv3-alongside-248/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nevermind. Some dependencies were using pre-built packages which used OpenCv 2.4.x. After recompiling these, everything worked fine.

---

Originally posted by [meleagrosy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20932/meleagrosy/) with karma: 36 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-08**:
Plz mark your own answer as accepted if issue is solved ;)

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-09-28**:
Could you clarify? Which dependencies in particular? Thanks.

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2015-10-06**:
I have the same problem. Could you explain me how to recompile to solve it? I am new here, thanks in advance